# JPA - How can an entity refer to two other entities involved in a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have the following tables:

[image]

In my domain model, I have a `Car` entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="CarClassType",
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="carId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="classTypeId"))
    private List<CarType> carTypes;
    
    private String model;
}
```

I also have a `CarClassTypeSale` and `ClassType` entities. I don't have a `CarClassType` entity. How should `CarClassTypeSale` class refer back to a `Car` and `ClassType`?

```
@Entity
@Data
public class CarClassTypeSale {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne // this doesn't work; errors with invalid column name
    private Car car;

    @ManyToOne // this doesn't work; errors with invalid column name
    private ClassType classType;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modelling here does not require a `@ManyToMany` as you can model the `CarClassType` as entity. Since the `CarClassType` table has an additional column `id`, you also actually can't model it this way. If you want this, you would have to use the two FKs also as primary key and drop the `id` column, which I would recommend you do anyway.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private Set<CarClassType> carTypes;
    
    private String model;
}
@Entity
@Data
public class CarClassType {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CarClassTypeId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "carId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Car car;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "classTypeId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private CarType classType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carClassType")
    private Set<CarClassTypeSale> sales = new HashSet<>();
}
@Embeddable
@Data
public class CarClassTypeId {

    @Column(name = "carId")
    private Integer carId;
    
    @Column(name = "classTypeId")
    private Integer classTypeId;
}
@Entity
@Data
public class CarClassTypeSale {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private CarClassType carClassType;

    private LocalDate soldDate;


}
```

Not sure how `CarClassTypeSale` fits into this picture. Your diagram does not really tell me how the class relates to the others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `CarClassTypeSale` captures the sale of a car belonging to a specific class type. So, a `CarClassTypeSale` refers to one `CarClassType`.  A record in `CarClassType` refers to one `Car` and one `ClassType`. Therefore, a `CarClassTypeSale` indirectly refers to one `Car` and one `ClassType`. Perhaps, I misunderstood your note about how it relates to others but I do see this relationship in the diagram.

Comment: Also, could you please tell me why you prefer getting rid of the `id` column of `CarClassType`? I agree that it's not needed if we make the FKs a compound PK but the `id` eliminates the  need of embeddable.

Comment: I updated the model. You were writing something about a many-to-many association, but this is not a many-to-many association if you introduce a surrogate `id`. Apart from that, you don't need to model this particular case as many-to-many and oftentimes one does not need a many-to-many association anyway. The model I posted should work for your case though.

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately, I'm trying to see if it was possible to **not** have an `CarClassType` entity. I could remove `id` column from the `CarClassType` table. As you noted, it's not necessary. But I think in order to define a relationship between `CarClassTypeSale` entity and the two entites `Car`  & `ClassType` , it is necessary to have a `CarClassType` entity, Do you agree?

Comment: You can model it in any way you like, but how you should model it should be driven by the requirements because this makes a difference semantically. I don't know your actual requirement, but in this particular example, I would just drop `CarClassType`.